# Design for downloading files before starting of an Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, design-patterns

I have a use case where I want to download some files from the server and store them locally before starting another activity that is dependent on this file. This kind of design can be found on karaoke kind of applications where clicking on one song would

1. Load the required files from the server
2. Once the download is finished, open the required activity.

Let us assume that my app is a karaoke app. My question is how to design this flow. Basically, on clicking on one song, I want to show progress on the screen and when the download is finished, I want to move to the activity. Another requirement is that once I am inside the karaoke activity screen and playing a song, I have an option which leads to loading of another lesson. If a user uses that option, I want to again download the required files. Based on this requirement, should I:

- Have the file loading thing as a separate activity?
  OR
- It can be used as `Fragment`inside the activity where I choose a particular song. In this case, once entering the karaoke screen, if I choose an option which leads to downloading some files and reloading of this activity, is this the best design?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two different approaches depending on how long you plan on keeping the data that you've downloaded. If it is single use than a bound service would be ideal. However, if you are planning on keeping the downloaded content for more than a single use, I would recommend you use a content provider and possibly a sync adapter(Depending on how frequent/predictable content downloading is). This combo would help guide you into not having to think about the 'design' as much(Since it is pretty standard at this point), plus it would provide a lot of features that you may/may not find useful: you can make your internal data 'public' via the content provider/authority(s), you can make an 'account' on the phone associated with your app so that the user can manage its syncing via the sync manager(actually via widgets/apps using the sync manager, but still), and most importantly a set of clean(ish)/standard means to interact with it/propagate UI, etc.

My simple version would be an Activity that spawns either a async-AIDL service with callback (which is in my opinion the only way to use a bound service) that would allow you to asynchronously design your 'starter' activity, its "currently downloading" spinner (which can get progress updates via the callback if you design it that way). Then once the download is complete then send the results (via a parcel file descriptor in the Intent's bundle) to the new activity that makes use of it.

However, if you are planning on using the data more than once, I'd recommend downloading the content like you did above, but then also store it in a content provider for easy access later. Providers also have a lot of nice associated functionality related to cursor loaders, etc. that will help keep a list of the content currently being stored nice and clean/up-to-date/dynamic/etc. However, this is a lot more work to setup once, then later it would save you time in reduced.

A sync adapter is best when the data to be downloaded is predictable, either based on user's account or temporally (such as someone having an account to download data from (email account, etc.) or when the target is fairly constant, but the data should be updated every hour or so(such as the current weather)). So this will depend a lot on your application's exact specifics.

Here is an assignment for an Android App Development course I wrote that is an even more simplified version of the first option (it has intent service + broadcast receiver for returning download results back to the Activity). Obviously since this is an assignment it has sections cut out to make skeleton code, but the documentation is ABSURDLY detailed and should be fairly easily implemented.

https://gitlab.com/vandy-aad-3/aad-3-assg-2/tree/master

Here is the extension of that assignment for that same course that focuses on implementing a simple content provider's 4 main methods (Create, Read, Update, & Delete). Everything else about the provider is given to you.

https://gitlab.com/vandy-aad-3/aad-3-assg-3/tree/master

Obviously the content being downloaded in both applications is probably not what you intended, but that is a simple swap to replace in what you do want.

Not to shill to hard, but here is the (free) Specialization that this course is a part of: https://www.coursera.org/learn/androidapps

Answer (score 0):

- Point one : Don't download video file within the `Activity` level. You can start a `Service` to handle it. Once the download function is finished you can start the second `Activity`. While download function is in progress you can show a `ProgressBar`
- Point Two : Best Design is show a `ProgressBar` with percentage to user. Or disable the function. After download complete enable or start the second activity.

Comment: Yeah. I got both the points. But, I am planning to use a design pattern mentioned in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentRetainInstance.java and use a background task fragment to download the files. My question is if the I should start different activity for downloading the files or should it be shown as a fragment on the activity where I clicked to open a particular song?

Comment: You can add `EventBus` library, What is does is send a `Event` between `Contexts`. So send  a `Event` to your `Activity` or `Fragment` when the download has completed. And through the event listener grab the object and update your Views